# Pseudorandom Cellular Automaton

Tags: code-golf, cellular-automata

### Introduction

In this challenge, we will simulate a certain [probabilistic cellular automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_cellular_automaton) using very bad pseudorandom numbers.
The cellular automaton is defined on binary strings by the following local rule.
Suppose that the left neighbor of a cell and the cell itself have states `a` and `b`.

- If `min(a,b) == 0`, then the new state of `b` is `max(a,b)`.
- If `min(a,b) == 1`, then the new state of `b` is chosen randomly from `{0,1}`.

The following picture shows one possible 10-step evolution of a single `1`.

```
1
11
101
1111
11001
101011
1111111
10001001
110011011
1010111101
```

Note how two adjacent `1`s sometimes evolve to `1`, and sometimes to `0`, and the border-most bits are always `1`s.
Your task is to produce a cellular automaton evolution of this form.

### Inputs

Your inputs are a positive integer `n`, denoting the number of rows to display, and a non-empty list of bits `L`, which we use as a source of randomness.

### Output

Your output is a list of lists or 2D array of bits, depicting the evolution of a single `1` for `n` time steps, as in the above figure.
You can pad the output with `0`s to get rows of equal lengths, if desired, but there must not be leading `0`s.

The random choices in the cellular automaton must be drawn from the list `L`, jumping back to the beginning when it is exhausted.
More explicitly, if the output is traversed one row at a time form top to bottom, left to right, then the successive random choices shall form the list `L` repeated as many times as necessary.

### Example

Suppose the inputs are `n = 7` and `L = [0,1,0]`.
Then the cellular automaton evolves as follows during the 7 steps, where we have put a `v` right above every random choice:

```
[1]

[1,1]
   v
[1,0,1]

[1,1,1,1]
   v v v
[1,1,0,0,1]
   v
[1,1,1,0,1,1]
   v v   v
[1,0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

If we read all the bits marked with a `v`, we get `01001001`, which is `L` repeated 2.66 times.
The next random bit would be `0`.

### Rules and Scoring

You can write a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.
The exact format of the inputs and outputs is unimportant (within reason).

### Test Cases

Deterministic version, every random bit is `0`:

```
Inputs: 10 [0]
Output:
1
11
101
1111
10001
110011
1010101
11111111
100000001
1100000011
```

Every random bit is `1`:

```
Inputs: 6 [1,1]
Output:
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111
```

Pseudorandom versions:

```
Inputs: 10 [0,0,1]
Output:
1
11
101
1111
10101
111111
1010011
11110101
101011111
1111101001

Inputs: 10 [1,0,0,1]
Output:
1
11
111
1001
11011
111111
1001101
11010111
111111101
1011001111

Inputs: 15 [1,1,1,0,0,0]
Output:
1
11
111
1111
10001
110011
1110111
11011001
111111011
1100011111
11100100011
111101100101
1001111101111
11011000111111
101101001011101
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, 33 bytes

```
jjLk.u++1m?hSde=.<Q1sd.:N2 1tvz]1
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jjLk.u%2B%2B1m%3FhSde%3D.%3CQ1sd.%3AN2%201tvz%5D1&test_suite_input=10%0A%5B0%5D%0A6%0A%5B1%2C1%5D%0A10%0A%5B0%2C0%2C1%5D%0A10%0A%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%0A15%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D&input_size=2&test_suite=0&input=15%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jjLk.u%2B%2B1m%3FhSde%3D.%3CQ1sd.%3AN2%201tvz%5D1&test_suite_input=10%0A%5B0%5D%0A6%0A%5B1%2C1%5D%0A10%0A%5B0%2C0%2C1%5D%0A10%0A%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%0A15%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D&input_size=2&test_suite=1&input=15%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D)

#### Explanation:

```
jjLk.u++1m?hSde=.<Q1sd.:N2 1tvz]1  implicit: Q = input list
    .u                      tvz]1  reduce N=[1] input-1 times by applying
                      .:N2           all substrings of length 2
         m                           map each d of ^ to:
          ?hSd                         if min(d) = 0 then:
               =.<Q1                     rotate Q by one
              e                          and use the last element
                    sd                 else use sum(d) (=max(d))
      ++1                  1         add a 1 at the front and the back
                                   .u gives all intermediate results
 jLk                               join these lists to strings
j                                  print each string on a line
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 139 bytes

```
^.
1

 00:0 01:1 10:1 11:
(m`^(..)((\S*)(?<=0) .*)
$1$3#$1!$2
+m`(?<=^(?<-2>.)*(..).*?#(.)*.)\d!(.)(.*\1:)(.)(\d*)
$5$3!$4$6$5
)`!0
0
 .+
<empty>
```

Where `<empty>` indicates that there is a trailing empty line. Each line goes in a separate file and the `#` should be replaced with linefeeds (0x0A).

Expects the input to be `n` in [unary](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary) (made of zeroes, as in [Unary](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary)), followed by a space, followed by the "pseudo-random" string, e.g. `10, [1, 0, 0, 1]` would be read as

```
0000000000 1001
```

Output is as in the challenge, but padded with zeroes, e.g.

```
1000000000
1100000000
1110000000
1001000000
1101100000
1111110000
1001101000
1101011100
1111111010
1011001111
```

This was way trickier than I expected...

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>142</s> <s>135</s> <s>132</s> 131 bytes

#### <s>133</s> <s>132</s> 131 byte version

```
f=input;n=f();L=f()*n*n;r=[1];i=1
while i<=n:print r;r=[L.pop(0)if r[x-1]&r[x]else r[x-1]+r[x]for x in range(1,i)];r=[1]+r+[1];i+=1
```

replaced `r[x-1]+r[x]>1` by `r[x-1]&r[x]` were the bitwise operator & yields the minimum value in `(r[x-1],r[x])`

Thanks @ThomasKwa for suggesting `n*n` instead of `n**2` which saves 1 byte!

Thanks @Shebang for the -1 byte

#### 135 byte version

```
f=input;n=f();L=f()*n**2;r=[1];i=1
while i<=n:print r;r=[L.pop(0)if r[x-1]+r[x]>1 else r[x-1]+r[x]for x in range(1,i)];r=[1]+r+[1];i+=1
```

Thanks to @Cole for the -7 bytes:

`min(r[x-1],r[x])->r[x-1]+r[x]>1`

`max(r[x-1],r[x])->r[x-1]+r[x]`

#### 142 byte version

```
f=input;n=f();L=f()*n**2;r=[1];i=1
while i<=n:print r;r=[L.pop(0)if min(r[x-1],r[x])else max(r[x-1],r[x])for x in range(1,i)];r=[1]+r+[1];i+=1
```

Not even close to @Jakube's answer but I had a lot of fun coding and golfing this one.

Expects two inputs: first input is the **number of rows** and second input is the **pseudorandomness source list**. It prints on console one row after another, each on a new line.

As an example:

```
10 # This is input
[0] # This is input
[1] <- First output row
[1, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

#### Now for a short explanation on how it works:

```
f=input;n=f();L=f()*n*n;r=[1];i=1 First we define the input() function as f 
                                   for saving bytes as we have to call it twice.
                                   Then L is defined as a list made of the 
                                   pseudorandom numbers in their order *many* times 
                                   (were *many* is an upperbound of the canges that 
                                   could be done); r as the first row and i as the row 
                                   counter.

while i<=n:print r                 A while loop that exits when the nth row has been 
                                   calculated and the printing of the actual row.

r=[L.pop(0)if r[x-1]&r[x] else r[x-1]+r[x] for x in range(1,i)];r=[1]+r+[1];i+=1
     ^           ^                 ^                         ^
     |           |                 |Same as max(r[x-1],r[x]) | from 2nd to last element
     |           | Same as min(r[x-1],r[x]) (0->False;1->True)                
     | get random bit from pseudorandom list
```

The trick here is that we know that the bit list will always start and end with a `1` because the first and last elements are never modified due to the specs. of the question. That's the reason for the statement `[1]+r+[1]`.

But if `r` is initialized as `[1]`, there are no changes on the first row and then we add `[1]+r+[1]` how come the second row is not `[1,1,1]`?

This is due to the fact that on the first iteration `i=1` so `range(1,i)` returns an empty list and, as a result of the `for` in the list comprehension having nothing to iterate over `r` becomes an empty list so `[1]+r+[1]=[1,1]`. This just happens on the first iteration which is just ideal for us!

P.S: Feel free to make any suggestions on how to golf it more.

Comment: My apologies if I don't understand the challenge correctly, but can't you replace `min(a,b)` with `a+b>1` and `max(a,b)` with `a+b`? I realize you'd probably have to do something to handle the very first case of `1` -> `11` (I think you could do `L=[1]+f()...`, or find some way to insert 1 in the front of `L` because that would always pop 1 for the second line)

Comment: @Cole Luckily no changes have to be made to the rest of the program as the changes only affect the way of knowing the min and max values of a pair of bits.

Comment: You missed that you can remove a space here: `r[x-1]&r[x] else` :)

Comment: Would n**2 -> n*n work?

Comment: @Thomas You're right!

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <strike>146</strike> <strike>143</strike> 138

(Also works on Octave online, but you need to sign in to save the function in a file).

```
function o=c(n,L);o=zeros(n);o(:,1)=1;for i=2:n;for j=2:i;a=o(i-1,j-1);b=o(i-1,j);c=a|b;d=a&b;c(d)=L(d);L=circshift(L,-d);o(i,j)=c;end;end
```

The function takes an input `n` and `L`, and returns an array `o` which contains the output.

For the input values, `n` is a scalar, and `L` is a column vector, which can be specified in the format `[;;;]`. Not quite what you show, but you say it is flexible within reason and this seems so.

The output is formatted as an `n x n` array containing 0's and 1's.

And an explanation:

```
function o=c(n,L)
%Create the initial array - an n x n square with the first column made of 1's
o=zeros(n);o(:,1)=1;
%For each row (starting with the second, as the first is done already)
for i=2:n;
    %For each column in that row, again starting with the second as the first is done
    for j=2:i;
        %Extract the current and previous elements in the row above
        a=o(i-1,j-1); %(previous)
        b=o(i-1,j);   %(current)
        %Assume that min()==0, so set c to max();
        c=a|b;
        %Now check if min()==1
        d=a&b;
        %If so, set c to L(1)
        c(d)=L(d);
        %Rotate L around only if min()==1
        L=circshift(L,-d);
        %And store c back to the output matrix
        o(i,j)=c;
    end;
end
```

---

Update: I have managed to optimise away the if-else statement to save a few bytes. The input format has once again changed back to column vector.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>153</s> 149 bytes

```
j[_]o l=(l,o)
j(a:u@(b:c))o q@(l:m)|a*b==0=j u(o++[a+b])q|1<2=j u(o++[l])m
k(r,a)=fmap((1:).(++[1]))$j a[]r
n%l=map snd$take n$iterate k(cycle l,[1])
```

`%` returns a list of bit lists. Usage example:

```
> 10 % [1,0,0,1] 
[[1],[1,1],[1,1,1],[1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]]
```

Oh dear! Carrying the random list `L` around is pure pain. Let's see if this can be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 152 bytes

There's nothing special here.  The function returns a 2D array where the first rank is the line and the second is the column.

Indented and new lines for clarity:

```
int[,]F(int n,int[]l){
    var o=new int[n,n];
    for(int y=0,x,i=0,m;y<n;y++)
        for(o[y,x=0]=1;x++<y;)
            o[y,x]=(m=o[y-1,x-1]+o[y-1,x])<2?m:l[i++%l.Length];
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, <s>106</s> <s>94</s> <s>87</s> <s>86</s> 87 bytes

```
Prompt N,B
"∟B(1+remainder(,dim(∟B→u
{1
For(I,1,N
Disp Ans
augment({0},Ans)+augment(Ans,{0
Ans and Ans≠2+seq(u(-(Ans(X)<2)+2dim(∟B)),X,1,dim(Ans
End
```

TI-BASIC doesn't have an increment operator, right? Well, it sort of does. The equation variable `u`, normally used with sequences, has an obscure feature: when `u` is called with an argument, the variable  is set to one greater than that argument. The conditional increment depends on this. (I've been waiting to use it for a long time.)

For list indexing to work properly,  must be its default value of 0, and `Min` should be its default 1, so either clear your calculator's RAM or set those values manually before running this.

`augment({0},Ans)+augment(Ans,{0` calculates a list of sums of two adjacent elements, so it will return a list of 0s, 1s, and 2s. Then the magic is on this line:

```
Ans and Ans≠2+seq(u(-(Ans(X)≠2)+dim(∟B)),X,1,dim(Ans

Ans and                 ;set 0s to 0
Ans≠                    ;set to 0 all sums that equal...
2+
  seq(...,X,1,dim(Ans   ;execute for each element of the list
      u(                ;return this element in list of bits (looping)        
                       ;current location in the list
        -(Ans(X)≠2)+    ;subtract 1 if the element isn't 2
        2dim(∟B)        ;Add twice the dimension of the list
                           ;(because n<nMin on the first iteration, it's out of the domain
                           ;this prevents an error)
       )                      ;set n to one greater than that value
                              ;i.e. increment if element≠2
                        ;Will equal Ans(X) iff Ans(X)=2 and the bit read false
```

The result of this line will be that list elements are 0 if they were 0 or if they were 2 and the bit read was 0.

```
Result of above line
n \ u |  0  |  1
0        0     0
```

Test case:

```
N=?7
B=?{0,1,0
             {1}
           {1 1}
         {1 0 1}
       {1 1 1 1}
     {1 1 0 0 1}
   {1 1 1 0 1 1}
 {1 0 0 1 1 1 1}
            Done
```